# How to make a 2d numpy array a 3d array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have a 2d array with shape (x, y) which I want to convert to a 3d array with shape (x, y, 1). Is there a nice Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you can also use slicing with [`numpy.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis):

```
>>> from numpy import zeros, newaxis
>>> a = zeros((6, 8))
>>> a.shape
(6, 8)
>>> b = a[:, :, newaxis]
>>> b.shape
(6, 8, 1)
```

Or even this (which will work with an arbitrary number of dimensions):

```
>>> b = a[..., newaxis]
>>> b.shape
(6, 8, 1)
```

Comment: On a side note, `numpy.newaxis` is just `None`. `newaxis` is "just" for readibility. It's equivalent to just do `b = a[..., None]` (The ellipsis also allows it to work for N-dimensional arrays, not just 2D arrays.)

Comment: True.  For some reason I had the impression that `newaxis` being `None` was just an implementation detail (and therefore possibly subject to change in the future), but it looks like it's explicitly documented.

Comment: Suppose you want the third axis to be something other than 1? e.g. how do you convert `a` to be `b` with `b.shape = (6,8,3)`?

Comment: @Gathide: That depends. Your old array has `6*8 = 48` numbers in it. The new one has `6*8*3 = 144` numbers. How do you want to map the original 48 numbers into your new array? Repeat along the third axis? In which case, most of the time you don't bother with the repetition: leave it as shape `(6, 8, 1)` and make use of NumPy's ability to broadcast.  But if you really need shape `(6, 8, 3)`, look into `np.tile` and `np.broadcast_to`.

Comment: @Gathide as Mark Dickinson says you can do this with `np.broadcast_to` like `b = np.broadcast_to(a[..., np.newaxis], (6, 8, 3))`.

Comment: @wingr, yes that is an option but as Mark Dickinson pointed out there will be repetition and hence shape `(6,8,1)` is preferred to shape `(6,8,3)`.

Comment: And how to proceed when the third dimension is a 2D array?

Comment: @user7924113: Are you asking about how to add _two_ new dimensions, to turn a 2d array into a 4d array? If so, `a[..., newaxis, newaxis]` would work, or `a[:, :, newaxis, newaxis]`, though of course you can put the new dimensions wherever you want with respect to the existing ones. If that's not what you're asking, maybe ask a new question? (The comments of this one probably aren't the right place to hash this out.)

Answer (score 20):

```
numpy.reshape(array, array.shape + (1,))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used A = A.reshape(A.shape + (1,))

Comment: If you're happy to modify `A` in place, you can simply assign to the shape attribute:  `A.shape = A.shape + (1,)`, or even `A.shape += 1,`.

Comment: assuming that i have a 3D [1000,10,5] array and I want to convert it to a 2D with shape [1000, 50] like concatenating the 2nd and 3rd initial dimensions. Is `reshape` fine in this case?

Comment: @serafeim, sure.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that the desired outcome is when I use `order='F'` inside `np.reshape`. If `order='F'` is NOT specified, then the output is wrong in my case

Answer (score 13):

```
import numpy as np

# create a 2D array
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3], [4,5,6],[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

print(a.shape) 
# shape of a = (8,3)

b = np.reshape(a, (8, 3, -1)) 
# changing the shape, -1 means any number which is suitable

print(b.shape) 
# size of b = (8,3,1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np

a= np.eye(3)
print a.shape
b = a.reshape(3,3,1)
print b.shape
```

Answer (score 3):

hope this funtion helps u to convert 2D array to 3D array.

```
Args:
  x: 2darray, (n_time, n_in)
  agg_num: int, number of frames to concatenate. 
  hop: int, number of hop frames. 

Returns:
  3darray, (n_blocks, agg_num, n_in)


def d_2d_to_3d(x, agg_num, hop):

    # Pad to at least one block. 
    len_x, n_in = x.shape
    if (len_x < agg_num): #not in get_matrix_data
        x = np.concatenate((x, np.zeros((agg_num - len_x, n_in))))

    # main 2d to 3d. 
    len_x = len(x)
    i1 = 0
    x3d = []
    while (i1 + agg_num <= len_x):
        x3d.append(x[i1 : i1 + agg_num])
        i1 += hop

    return np.array(x3d)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a 3rd axis (x,y) to (x,y,1), Numpy allows you to easily do this using the `dstack` command.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.eye(3) # your matrix here
b = np.dstack(a).T
```

You need to transpose (`.T`) it to get it into the (x,y,1) format you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with reshape

For example, you have an array A of shape 35 x 750 (two dimensions), you can change the shape to 35 x 25 x 30 (three dimensions) with A.reshape(35, 25, 30)

More in the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape)

Answer (score 1):

**simple way , with some math**

at first you know the number  of array elements , lets say 100
and then devide 100 on 3 steps like:

25 * 2 * 2 = 100

or: 4 * 5 * 5 = 100

```
import numpy as np
D = np.arange(100)
# change to 3d by division of 100 for 3 steps 100 = 25 * 2 * 2
D3 = D.reshape(2,2,25) # 25*2*2 = 100
```

another way:

```
another_3D = D.reshape(4,5,5)
print(another_3D.ndim)
```

to 4D:

```
D4 = D.reshape(2,2,5,5)
print(D4.ndim)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
# create a 2-D ndarray
a = np.array([[2,3,4], [5,6,7]])
print(a.ndim)
>> 2
print(a.shape)
>> (2, 3)

# add 3rd dimension
```

**1st option: reshape**

```
b = np.reshape(a, a.shape + (1,))
print(b.ndim)
>> 3
print(b.shape)
>> (2, 3, 1)
```

**2nd option: expand_dims**

```
c = np.expand_dims(a, axis=2)
print(c.ndim)
>> 3
print(c.shape)
>> (2, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array

```
a2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3.3],
           [4, 5, 6.5]])
```

then you can change this array into 3-d array of `shape (2, 3, 3)` by using:

`a2_new = np.reshape(a2, a2.shape + (1,)) a2_new`

Your **Output** will be:

```
array([[[1. ],
    [2. ],
    [3.3]],

   [[4. ],
    [5. ],
    [6.5]]])
```

**OR**
You can try:

```
a2.reshape(2, 3, 1)
```

this will change your 2-d array to 3-d of `shape(2, 3, 1)`.