# Reshape sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix (scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix) and I want to reshape it from (4137, 3000) to (4137, 3000, 1) I found that scipy has scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.reshape but when I perform for example:

```
x = x.reshape((x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1))
```

I get the same shape! not 3D

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's not you, it's them. AKAIK scipy.sparse supports 2D only.

Comment: *"... I get the same shape!"*  Hmmm.  That should probably raise an exception.

Comment: New issue on github for this: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9994

Answer (score 0):

Scipy can't do this for you, but numpy can!

For example:

```
>>> from numpy import zeros, newaxis
>>> a = zeros((6, 8))
>>> a.shape
(6, 8)
>>> b = a[:, :, newaxis]
>>> b.shape
(6, 8, 1)
```

Simply provide your array and use `newaxis`

From: [How to make a 2d numpy array a 3d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372316/how-to-make-a-2d-numpy-array-a-3d-array)