# Adding dimension to ndarray and reshaping

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array that has shape of (16,2)

```
[[-109.12722222    1454.        ]
 [-109.12694444    1459.        ]
 [-109.12666667    1463.        ]
 [-109.12638889    1465.        ]
 [-109.12611111    1464.        ]
 [-109.12583333    1464.        ]
 [-109.12555556    1464.        ]
 [-109.12527778    1464.        ]
 [-109.125         1464.        ]
 [-109.12472222    1465.        ]
 [-109.12444444    1465.        ]
 [-109.12416667    1463.        ]
 [-109.12388889    1462.        ]
 [-109.12361111    1461.        ]
 [-109.12333333    1459.        ]
 [-109.12305556    1454.        ]]
```

and I want to know how to reshape it so it is (4,4,2).

```
[[-109.12722222    1454.        ] [-109.12694444    1459.        ][-109.12666667    1463.        ][-109.12638889    1465.        ]
 [-109.12611111    1464.        ] [-109.12583333    1464.        ] [-109.12555556    1464.        ][-109.12527778    1464.        ]
 [-109.125         1464.        ][-109.12472222    1465.        ][-109.12444444    1465.        ][-109.12416667    1463.        ]
 [-109.12388889    1462.        ][-109.12361111    1461.        ][-109.12333333    1459.        ][-109.12305556    1454.        ]]
```

I tried this:

```
numpy_array = np.reshape(4, 4, 2)
```

but it throws:

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (4,)

Comment: Where's the array that you are trying to reshape?

Comment: how can you convert 2 dimensional array to three dimensional?

Comment: @Kishan there were people who did it here, but when I did that it still threw the same error    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372316/how-to-make-a-2d-numpy-array-a-3d-array

Comment: You code does not match any of these examples in that link.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on how to use `numpy.reshape` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html?

Comment: `np.reshape(4,4,2)` is trying to change the array `np.array([4])` in to a size (4,) array.  You did not give the function the (16,2) shaped array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [numpy.newaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((16, 2))
b = a[:, :, np.newaxis]
c = b.reshape(4, 4, 2)

print(c.shape)
```

Comment: Got it! I realized what I was forgetting, thanks for the answer.

Comment: `a.reshape(4,4,2)` or `np.reshape(a, (4,4,2))` would work just as well.  You don't need the `newaxis` step.